# Howto package a android webapp for the Google Play store?

Tags: android, web-applications, packaging, google-play

I would like to publish my web application for free in the Google Play store (for the exposure).

All descriptions I found so far are for native apps. Is it possible to submit a HTML only app ? How would an example manifest file look and how do I sign such an app ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Comment: @Paul: I've read through that page, but I don't see it saying all apps must be in Java, yet all descriptions of the publishing process include signing a jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to create a webview using Android Java libraries, and then display your webapp inside of that webview. Normally if you're not doing Java you'd want to do something like PhoneGap.